# How to call my Stored Procedure with parameters form a Domain Class in Grails

Tags: grails, stored-procedures

Need a sample for How to call my Stored Procedure form a Domain Class in Grails.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stored procedure supporer by [Groovy SQL](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features).

Define dataSource in your Domain (its spring bean and will be injected)
Create Sql object using dataSource and use sql to execute your stored procedure.

```
class myDomain{
    def dataSource

  myMethod{
        Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        sql.call("{? = call FullName(?)}", [Sql.VARCHAR, 'Sam']) { name ->
          ....
        }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Grails is just a spring application so you may use any spring api in your grails application. In this case we can use [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) class to call stored procedure.

Here is a sample code how you can use JdbcTemplate in your service class taken from [This post](http://www.rimple.com/tech/2010/3/25/calling-postgresql-stored-procedures-from-grails-part-1-the.html).

```
class StoredProcedureRunnerService {
 def dataSource
 boolean transactional = true

 // automatically set up by name (Spring injected) on startup
 def sumBookSalesByBookIdWithJdbcTemplate(def bookId) {
     def template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource)
        template.queryForInt("select salesByBookId(${bookId})")
     }
  }
```